# -3 is quadratic residue if and only if $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod {12}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, congruences, quadratic-residues

I have to prove that -3 is quadratic residue if and only if $$p \equiv 1,7 \pmod {12}$$
I know one method (with symbol Legendre'a) but I don't get. If someone can explain me I will be happy or give another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Legendre symbol is the easiest way to do it... Just use the properties:
$$ \left( \frac{-3}{p} \right)=\left( \frac{3}{p} \right)\left( \frac{-1}{p} \right)$$

Now $\left( \frac{-1}{p} \right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ which can easily be evaluated.

Next for $\left( \frac{3}{p} \right)$ you could use the formula given in the wikipedia article or the quadratic reciprocity law
$$ \left( \frac{p}{q} \right)\left( \frac{q}{p} \right)=(-1)^{(p-1)(q-1)/4}$$
which for $p=3$ gives
$$ \left( \frac{p}{3} \right)\left( \frac{3}{p} \right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$$

Note that $\left( \frac{p}{3} \right)$ is easily computable since a number is quadratic residue modulo $3$ if it has residue $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$.

Now the rest it's just casework modulo $12$.

Comment: but how can i transform this modulo 12?

Comment: For example -2 is quadratic residue p ≡ 1,3 mod 8 and there are
(-1/p)=(2/p) = 1 or -1. it's +1 when p ≡ 1,5 mod 8 and 1,7 mod 8. Where does it come from

Comment: Start with $p \equiv 1$ modulo $12$. Then $p\equiv 1$ modulo $3$ and $1$ modulo $2$. Therefore $(-1/p) = 1$ and $(1/3)(3/p) = 1$. Thus $(-3/p) =1$. Do the same thing for $p\equiv 5,7,11$ to see what works. Note that all other residues will not give primes...

Comment: From what is modulo 2?

Comment: I wanted to say modulo $4$ which allows to say the parity of $(p-1)/2$...

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=\left(\frac{-1}p\right)\left(\frac{3}p\right)$$

so $\;\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=1\iff\;$  either both $\;-1,3\;$ are quadratic residues modulo $\;p\;$ or both aren't.

**If they both are**: then

$$p=1\pmod 4\implies p=1,5,9\pmod{12}$$

but it also must be $\;p=1\pmod 3\; $ ( we're assuming $\;p>3\;$) , so the only options left is $\;p=1\pmod 3\;$

**If the both aren't** : then

$$p=3\mod 4\;\;\text{and also}\;\;p=1\pmod 3 -- \text{because}\;\;\left(\frac3p\right)=-\left(\frac p3\right)\;\;\text{by QR}\;--\implies$$

$$\implies p=7\pmod{12}$$

Comment: For example -2 is quadratic residue p ≡ 1,3 mod 8 and there are (-1/p)=(2/p) = 1 or -1. it's +1 when p ≡ 1,5 mod 8 and 1,7 mod 8. Where does it come from ?

Comment: And why if the both aren't it's p=3 (mod 4) and also p =1 (mod 3) ?

Comment: First comment: $\;-2=1\pmod 3\;$ . Second comment: it is explained why. Do you know Quadratic Reciprocity?

Comment: Yes i know but I have problem with using this.

Comment: @zxc Remember that if $\;p,q\;$ are primes, then $$\left(\frac pq\right)=\left(\frac qp\right)\iff p,q=1\pmod4 $$ otherwise we have to multiply the right side by $\;-1\;$ .

Comment: Ok I understand where they both are and  I understand p=3 mod 4 but second p=1 mod 3? I don't know from where does it come from? Can you explain?

Comment: Since both $\;3,p=3\pmod 4\;$ , then $\;\left(\frac 3p\right)=\color{red}-\left(\frac p3\right)\;$ , so you have minus times minus equals plus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40761/discussion-between-zxc-and-joanpemo).

Comment: Ok so p =3 mod 4 ⟹ p = 3,7,11 <12>
and from p=2 mod 3 ⟹ p = 2, 5, 8, 10 <12>  something goes wrong why it should be p=1 mod 3?

Comment: Because you need both factors to be (-1) and when you turn upside down the factor $\;\frac3p\;$ it is automatically multiplied by $\;-1\;$ because both numbers there are $\;3\pmod 4\;$ ...I really can't make this more explicit anymore, sorry.