# $5$ is quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if $ p\equiv \pm 1, \pm 9 \pmod {20}$

Tags: quadratics, congruences, legendre-symbol, congruence-relations

5 is quadric residue  mod p if and only if $ p\equiv +/- 1, +/-9 \pmod {20}$

$$(5/p)=(p/5)$$
$p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ ⟹  $1,5,9,13,17 \pmod {20}$
$p\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ ⟹  $1,6,11,16 \pmod {20}$ 
then $p\equiv 1 \pmod {20}$
$p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ ⟹  $1,5,9,13,17 \pmod {20}$
$p\equiv 4 \pmod 5$ ⟹  $4,9,14,19 \pmod {20}$ 
then $p\equiv 9 \pmod {20}$

And now I should show that $$(5/p)=-(p/5)$$
$p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ ⟹  $3,7,11,15,19 \pmod {20}$
and p is congruent to 2 mod 5 it's p ≡ 7 mod 20
and p ≡3 mod 5 it's p ≡3 mod 20

And it doesn't +/-1 and +/-9 Why?

Please of help.

Comment: Simpler: for prime $p$ other than $2$ or $5$, $5 \equiv \Box \bmod p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1$ or $4 \bmod 5$.

Comment: So Is this correct what I wrote?

Comment: I am saying that the equivalence in your subject line is equivalent to what I wrote. For more, use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: I use it but it doesn't work

Comment: @KCd the equivalence requires the additional fact that a prime other than 2 is odd.

Comment: @Aaron, look again at what I wrote. It started by specifying $p$ is not $2$ or $5$.

Comment: @KCd what is wrong what I wrote under (5/p)=−(p/5)

Comment: @KCd Yes, what you wrote is just quadratic reciprocity.  But to go from what $p$ is mod $5$ to what it is mod $20$ (and getting the list in OP's title) requires noticing again that primes are odd.  It's not that you don't have the required hypotheses, it's that the hypotheses have to be further appreciated to make the conversion.

Comment: @zxc By quadratic reciprocity, it will never happen that (5/p)=-(p/5)

Comment: @Aaron can  you tell me what is wrong under (5/p)=−(p/5)

Comment: @Aaron so how can i prove that it will be also -1 and -9?

Comment: You asked a similar question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815126/3-is-quadratic-residue-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-7-pmod-12. Learn how to deduce things like these quadratic residue conditions from quadratic reciprocity instead of avoiding it.

Comment: @Aaron It happens (5/p)=+1 if and only if (p/5)= -1

Comment: @zxc In quadratic reciprocity, if either of $p$ or $q$ is congruent to $1 \mod 4$, then $(p/q)=(q/p)$.  So if $(5/p)=1$, then $(p/5)=1$, and if $(5/p)=-1$, then $(p/5)=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $5\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have $(5/p)=(p/5)$ by quadratic reciprocity, so there is no second case.  The squares mod $5$ are $\pm 1$.  Modulo $20$, this gives $1,4,6,9,11,14,16,19$.  However, because primes are odd, this eliminates all the even numbers in the list, leaving just $1,9,11,19$, which is the same as $\pm 1, \pm 9 \pmod{20}$

Comment: Thank you for explanation.